# Can I export token through features

Tags: 7, tokens

Can I export token through features from one environment to another

Comment: Where are you using the tokens you are trying to export?

Tokens are made available for use by the user but when you use a token (enter it into a form) you are saving it in a specific form.

Depending on the form you may or may not be able to export it via features. If it's stored as a variable you can use strongarm, most modules store settings this way.

Comment: I am using custom_token

Comment: I have created tokens using custom_token modules

Answer (score 1):

No - at this point it is not possible to export tokens using the custom tokens module. There is an [open issue](https://drupal.org/node/1341514) here on Drupal.org referring to this that has been waiting for a while without response and its unlikely the module maintainers will add this functionality as this is meant as a simple solution for developers who don't want to create their own tokens in PHP.

Depending on the complexity of your token operation, the best option might be to either manually sync up the two environments or to create your own custom token function following the instructions [here](https://drupal.org/node/1308488) (or other guides on the web). I would encourage you to try writing your own export functionality, its easier than it would seem and will open up more possibilities for you on future projects.